# SQL Group by return all rows except

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, group-by, max

I want from my Calls table all records that are not scheduled the latest for each patient.

```
callID  patientID scheduledDatetime
1       101       1/1/18 12:00:00
2       101       1/1/18 19:00:00
3       101       1/1/18 20:00:00
4       202       2/3/18 00:00:00
5       303       1/1/18 00:00:00
6       303       2/1/18 00:00:00
```

So the query should return:

```
callID  patientID scheduledDatetime
1       101       1/1/18 12:00:00
2       101       1/1/18 19:00:00
5       303       1/1/18 00:00:00
```

What I tried so far was eliminating any patients who only had one call, but I'm not sure how to filter out the latest calls for each patient:

```
select * from Calls C
where C.patientID in(
    select CL.patientID from Calls CL
    group by CL.patientID
    having COUNT(CL.callID) > 1
    --and CL.scheduledDatetime <> MAX(CL.scheduledDatetime)
)
```

Comment: First of all write your effort, your code

Comment: Do you want to select the _only_ record for 202?

Comment: @SalmanA No I do not since that call is technically the latest call for that patient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `self join` to capture only records which have a related later record:

```
SELECT DISTINCT NotLatestRecord.*
FROM mytable NotLatestRecord
INNER JOIN mytable LaterRecord
ON NotLatestRecord.patientID = LaterRecord.patientID
AND NotLatestRecord.scheduledDatetime < LaterRecord.scheduledDatetime
```

Answer (score 3):

A simple way uses `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by patientid order by scheduleddatetime desc) as seqnm
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum >= 2;
```

Under some circumstances, it may be more efficient to use a correlated subquery, though:

```
select t.*
from t
where exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where t2.patientid = t.patientid and t2.scheduleddatetime > scheduleddatetime
             );
```

Comment: If there are multiple calls for a patient scheduled at the exact same datetime, I would technically not want those calls included, which is what would result with the row_number() query. If anything, I would only want one of those calls to appear.

Comment: @GinoCortes . . . Then the first query is the best way to answer the question.